# New to C++, program not responding when dereferencing part of a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I learned C++ yesterday an I'm trying to solve USACO training problems.
http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=iKSzALidh4Q&S=gift1

For this one, I have created a vector of `People` pointers. However, after some troubleshooting, I discovered that when I try to do something like

```
Person bob = *(people.at(i));
```

or

```
people.at(i) -> setbalance(giveself); // giveself is an int
```

The program is not responding and:
Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s).

I'm also new to this forum.
Here is my code:
   include statments

```
using namespace std;

class Person

{
private:

    int balance;
    int origbalance;
    string name;
public:
    int getbalance() {return balance;}
    string getname() {return name;}
    void setbalance(int b){balance +=b;}
    void setorigbalance(int o) {origbalance = o;}
    int getorigbalance() {return origbalance;}
    void giveTo(int num, Person* y) {y->setbalance(num);}
    ~Person();

    Person(string n);
};

Person::Person(string n)
{
    name = n;
}

Person::~Person()
{
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
    ifstream fin ("gift1.in");

    int NP;
    fin>>NP;
    cout<<NP<<endl;
    vector<Person*> people(NP);

    cout<<"Created vector\n"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<NP; i++)
    {
        string nam;

        fin>>nam;
        Person* p = new Person(nam);
        people.push_back(p);
        cout<<nam<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nFilled vector, size = "<<people.size()<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<NP; i++)
    {
        string temp;
        fin>>temp;
        cout<<"\nNow receiving "<<temp<<endl;

        int togive, numgiving;
        fin>>togive>>numgiving;
        cout<<"\n"<<temp<<" is dividing "<<togive<<" among "<<numgiving<<"     people"<<endl;

        Person bob = *(people.at(i));
        cout<<"hi bob"<<endl;

        //(*people.at(i)).setorigbalance(togive);
        cout<<"Original balance set"<<endl;

        int giveeach = togive/numgiving;
        cout<<"or "<<giveeach<<" to each person"<<endl;
        int giveself = togive%numgiving;
        cout<<"and "<<giveself<<" to himself :/"<<endl;
        people.at(i) -> setbalance(giveself);

        for(int j=0; j<numgiving; j++)
        {
            string nametogiveto;
            fin>> nametogiveto;

            cout<<nametogiveto<<endl;

            for(int k=0; k<NP; k++)
            {
                string namy = people.at(k)->getname();
                if(namy==nametogiveto)
                {
                    cout<<"\nHere you go "<<namy<<" have "<<giveeach<<endl;
                    people.at(k)->setbalance(giveeach);
                    people.at(i)->setbalance(-giveeach);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<NP; i++)
    {
        cout<<people.at(i)->getname()<<endl;;
        cout<<people.at(i)->getorigbalance() - people.at(i)->getbalance()<<endl;
        cout<<endl;

        fout<<people.at(i)->getname();
        fout<<people.at(i)->getorigbalance() - people.at(i)->getbalance()<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the guides for new members, particularly the section on [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is too much code for such a simple problem. If you reduce it to the simplest code that produces the error, you will probably discover the bug without help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into **undefined behavior** due to dereferencing null pointers.

```
vector<Person*> people(NP);
```

This line creates the vector with `NP` null pointers. You later add on your actual pointers but only ever access the first `NP` elements which are the null pointers.

That said you don't even need pointers here and I'd recommend getting rid of them. In fact you have memory leaks due to allocating pointers with `new` but never calling `delete` on them. In my experience it's typical for people just starting out with C++ to overuse pointers, so think about ways to avoid them first.

Change

```
vector<Person*> people(NP);
```

to

```
vector<Person> people;
```

and fill it using:

```
for(int i = 0; i<NP; i++)
{
    string nam;

    fin>>nam;
    Person p(nam); // no more need for pointer or new here
    people.push_back(p);
    cout<<nam<<endl;
}
```

later when accessing it you don't need any dereferencing anymore either. That means you can get rid of all the `*` for example:

```
Person bob = *(people.at(i));
```

turns into:

```
Person bob = people.at(i);
```

and you can access member functions with `.` instead of `->` everywhere, for example:

```
people.at(k)->setbalance(giveeach);
```

would turn into:

```
people.at(k).setbalance(giveeach);
```

This means getting rid of a lot of unneeded dereferencing of pointers and also of the memory leak you previously would have had.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems that you are getting that error since opening input file `fin` is not successful. To check it, add the following line after you define `fin` variable:

```
ifstream fin ("gift1.in");
if(!fin) {
    cout << "Error opening input file.\n";
}
```

In any case, it's always a good practice to check if the file is opened successfully.